# Error while trying to start docker daemon service using systemctl (CoreOS)

Tags: docker, systemd

Following is the error I am getting while trying to start the docker daemon service

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─50-docker-service.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-08-22 02:09:40 UTC; 15min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 3571 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 292ms

Aug 22 02:09:40 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 22 02:09:40 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 22 02:09:40 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 22 02:09:40 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 22 02:09:40 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 22 02:09:40 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 22 02:09:40 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 22 02:09:40 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Below is the config files I have

50-docker-service.conf

```
    [Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=--bip=A.B.C.D"
```

what could be the cause?

```
$ls -ltr /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
total 16
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 125 Aug 22 02:09 50-docker-service.conf
```

journalctl logs

```
Jul 14 13:55:52  systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jul 14 13:55:52  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:55:52.925276313Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"overlay\""
Jul 14 13:55:53  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:55:53.378204522Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Jul 14 13:55:53  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:55:53.379367854Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jul 14 13:55:53  dockerd[1274]: ..time="2017-07-14T13:55:53.507972850Z" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Jul 14 13:55:54  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:55:54.013379242Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jul 14 13:55:54  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:55:54.021206395Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jul 14 13:55:54  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:55:54.021283711Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=a82d35e graphdriver=overlay version=1.12.6
Jul 14 13:55:54  systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 14 13:55:54  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:55:54.039479153Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Jul 14 13:56:03  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:56:03.565234227Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.24/containers/7019b26d0cb3/start returned error: Container already started"
Jul 14 13:56:09  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:56:09.660967581Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.24/containers/7019b26d0cb3/start returned error: Container already started"
Jul 14 13:56:14  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T13:56:14.741806551Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.24/containers/d9a3cb2b66e0/start returned error: Container already started"
Jul 14 21:05:16  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T21:05:16.992138499Z" level=info msg="Container 7019b26d0cb31412f40f8ab7f971f26896debcce09a58c39679dbaf62f6caa0b failed to exit within 0 s
Jul 14 21:07:20  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T21:07:20.897682536Z" level=info msg="Container d9a3cb2b66e0395086decd444f7ef52775f76f64b8d4dc291ee66cca48e53535 failed to exit within 2 s
Jul 14 21:08:08  systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Jul 14 21:08:08  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T21:08:08.243279424Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Jul 14 21:08:18  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T21:08:18.244896088Z" level=info msg="Container 9966c97ca301ef593a68ab8e50730552dbe945c42e6b530d4c6339d3ffa8f544 failed to exit within 10
Jul 14 21:08:18  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T21:08:18.244909995Z" level=info msg="Container d94a3d0c45471753da85fce062e3c56c79c14ad40b6870281515333b98d0807e failed to exit within 10
Jul 14 21:08:18  dockerd[1274]: time="2017-07-14T21:08:18.244936931Z" level=info msg="Container b49d40479583c121ae7abe14489c7121a25a56da00f3d25961f981c918d3257e failed to exit within 10
Jul 14 21:08:18  systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Comment: Run `journalctl -n 10 -f` and try restart and see what errors do you see? Also do `cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` you will find that the service doesn't use `DOCKET_OPTS` now it was with old services, so what you are trying to may not work. See this https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9889

Comment: reboot your machine and try again, it may works for you as  i had same issue with centos. the issue is gone when i restarted it.

Comment: no luck. tried rebooting the system also `Failed Units: 2
  docker.service
  docker.socket`

Answer (score 0):

Docker bridge ip is not configured properly.

```
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=--bip=A.B.C.D
```

Instead configured bip with a fully qualified CIDR

```
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=--bip=A.B.C.D/size
```

that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Check ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

is not modified in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service